# How can I go backward in time using datenum?

Tags: matlab

I have these two dates.

```
startTime = '4/2/2004 12:45'
endTime = '4/3/2004 18:15'
```

I want to find the time that is exactly 1.5*(startTime-endTime) in the past. And in the format I have rather than datenum. The time progresses in 5 minute steps in my dataset.

I am doing this, but not sure where to go from where:

```
startTime = datenum('4/2/2004 12:45');
endTime = datenum('4/3/2004 18:15');
```

Finally, I do something like this to generate filenames for some batch processing.

```
 for l = 1:timeSteps
       precipFileNames{l} = strcat(fileparts(refFile), filesep,'RATE.',datestr(startTime, 'yyyymmdd.hhMMss'), '.tif');
       startTime = addtodate(startTime, 5, 'minute');     
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You can use at least two different approaches, `datetime` or `datenum`.
Using `datenum`:

```
startTime = datenum('4/2/2004 12:45');
endTime = datenum('4/3/2004 18:15');
anotherTime = now;
inPast = anotherTime + (startTime - endTime) * 1.5;
datestr(inPast, 'yyyymmdd.hhMMss');
```

Or, using `datetime`:

```
startTime = datetime('4/2/2004 12:45', 'Format', 'MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm')
endTime = datetime('4/3/2004 18:15', 'Format', 'MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm')
anotherTime = datetime;
inPast = anotherTime + (startTime - endTime) * 1.5;
datestr(inPast, 'yyyymmdd.hhMMss');
startTime = startTime + minutes(5);
```

Comment: Thank you. In the first option, I am getting this error: Undefined function 'datetime' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: in the second option, what is datetime? :::::  anotherTime = datenum(datetime)

Comment: @maximusdooku `datetime` was only added in 2014b, so you may not have it. Re `datenum(datetime)` I have replaced it with the equivalent `now`. From your question it was not clear from which time you want to go back, so I took current time. But you could use any time parsed with `datenum`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't know the starting time (i.e. anotherTime). anotherTime is 1.5(startTime-endTime) in the past from the endTime. So, it will have to calculate the 1.5(start-end) from the endTime, and start the list from that time.....Was I able to explain myself clearly?

Comment: @maximusdooku I think in that case `anotherTime=endTime;` is why you want. That will give you that time point in the past